# Kivy progressbar changing color without kv

Tags: python, kivy, progress-bar

Hi I want to change the color of my kivy progressBar without a kv file, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the snippet I found online:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle

class CustomProgressBar(ProgressBar):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomProgressBar, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # Set initial color
        self.color = [1, 0, 0, 1]  # Red color

    def set_color(self, color):
        self.color = color

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        self.progress_bar = CustomProgressBar(max=100)
        layout.add_widget(self.progress_bar)

        # Change color after 2 seconds
        Clock.schedule_once(self.change_color, 2)

        return layout

    def change_color(self, dt):
        # Change the color of the progress bar
        self.progress_bar.set_color([0, 1, 0, 1])  # Green color

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Using functions `Clock.schedule_once()` and `set_color()` change the color to your prefered color and don't forget to change either the RGBA values or the interval

Comment: This doesn't change the color sadly, it stays the default blue no matter the color value.

Comment: The `ProgressBar` does not have a `color` attribute. Try using `MDProgressBar`.

Comment: MDProgressBar was the solution, thank you.